# Tkinter button border not disappearing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to place an image button in a Tkinter program, but there is an ugly grey border around the button which does not seem to disappear whatever I do. My current code is

```
self.true_image = PhotoImage(file="true.gif")
        self.true_button = Button(image=self.true_image, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                  bg=THEME_COLOR, activebackground=THEME_COLOR,
                                  fg=THEME_COLOR, padx=0, pady=0, borderwidth=0,
                                  relief='flat')
        self.true_button.grid(column=0, row=2)
```

as can be seen I have used every single command I could find related to this topic, adding them one by one, but none of them seem to work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el9Ll.png)

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: some system may not have function to remove it. OR maybe this line is on image and you have to edit image. Better add image to question and create minimal working code so we could simply copy and test it. OR maybe it is boder of other widget. You don't have `parent` in `Button` so we don't know if you put it directly in main window or in other widget.

Comment: Please attach `true.gif` to your question.